# SparkHadoopWriter Failing with NPE at UserProvider

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am using Spark to write data to Hbase, I can read data just fine but write is failing with following exception.  I found similar issue that got resolved by adding *site.xml and hbase JARs.  But it is not working for me. I am trying to read data from a table write data to another table.  i can read data just fine but getting exception while writing.

```
     JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>  tablePuts = hBaseRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>() {      
            @Override
            public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> results) throws Exception {
                        byte[] accountId = results._2().getValue(Bytes.toBytes(COLFAMILY), Bytes.toBytes("accountId"));                       
                        String rowKey = new String(results._2().getRow();
String accountId2 = (Bytes.toString(accountId));
                        String prefix = getMd5Hash(rowKey);
                        String newrowKey = prefix + rowKey; 
                        Put put = new Put( Bytes.toBytes(newrowKey) );
                        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("def"), Bytes.toBytes("accountId"), accountId);

                    }
                });
    Job newAPIJobConfiguration = Job.getInstance(conf);
        newAPIJobConfiguration.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, OUT_TABLE_NAME);
        newAPIJobConfiguration.setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.class);
        newAPIJobConfiguration.setOutputKeyClass(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        newAPIJobConfiguration.setOutputValueClass(org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable.class);
        tablePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newAPIJobConfiguration.getConfiguration());
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(TableOutputFormat.java:177)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.assertConf(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1083)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(JavaPairRDD.scala:831)
        at com.voicebase.etl.s3tohbase.HbaseScan2.main(HbaseScan2.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: I had the same issue by calling the method _saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile_. Apperently, _org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil_ initialializes the table output format without setting the configuration on this object. I use _saveAsHadoopFile_ instead.

Comment: You can also set spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs=false

But I'm convinced that there is a bug in _HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil_.